# Oracle Siebel Open UI command to get the Id of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle

I am new to Oracle Siebel Open UI  . I want to know how to get the id of dynamically generated applet. I tried using this.GetPM().Get("ID"). But, it is not working. In JQuery we have $('#test')('id'); What do we have in Siebel Open UI ?  Can you please on this. Thank you.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Krishna,
          We can get the applet id in two ways,

    #1 --> We can take the current applet id using following code:
           this.Get("GetFullId");          (in PM file)
           this.GetPM().Get("GetFullId");  (in PR file)

    #2 --> We can take any of the applet id present in the view using below Code:
           SiebelApp.S_App.GetActiveView().GetApplet("Applet_Name").GetFullId();
```